# HTML5 Canvas resize memory leak (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm working on a HTML5-based browser game that has a full-page canvas. It means that the size of the canvas corresponds to the window's dimensions. Width and height are changed when the window is resized, which works like a charm. The problem is with Chrome (34.0.1847.116): When you change these values, a decent amount of virtual memory gets allocated thus making the application slow. After 1-2 minutes of constant resizing it used more than 7 GB of memory. It is not shown in 'chrome://memory-redirect/', only in task manager. IE11 is not producing this symptom.

The following snippet is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. Create a canvas with id 'test' and try to resize the window. Higher the resolution the more memory consumed.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function resize() {
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
```

Is it possible to get this mechanic work in Chrome?

Comment: "One to two minutes of constant resizing" who is going to do that? This looks like a bug, but I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the amount of event handlings when resizing by delaying the resizing itself:

```
// must be in global scope
var canvas = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var delay;

function resize() {
    clearTimeout(delay);               // clear current timer if any
    delay = setTimeout(function() {    // new timer
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }, 260);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
```

When you now resize the actual resize will be delayed, here 260 ms, if no resize occur in between the resize will take place. If a new resize happen it will again be postponed.

Adjust the delay to suit your need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't solve the leak itself, but now it's hardly noticeable. Thanks a lot, your solution is a great workaround until Chrome gets fixed.